# Service injection in Guards and Circular Dependency

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm currently struggling with service injection in a guard.

Well, the thing is I made a `JwtAuthGuard`, that needs both my `FirebaseService` and my `UserService`.

So I thought it'd be useful to create a `AuthGuardModule` so i only need to import my `AuthGuardModules` in the modules that have a `Controller`, to use my Guard.

The thing is that unfortunately, i need this guard for my `UserModule` too.
So that's natural that i get a `Circular Dependency Error` When i import my `AuthGuardModule` in my `UserModule`.

Then, i tried all the things more or less related to `Circular Dependency Error` in Nest.js, but no can do.

Can someone tell me if:

- I am totally wrong thinking about making a module only for my guards ?
- If I'm not, how can I fix my `Circular Dependency Error` ?
- If I misunderstood that part, why isn't it right and what's the best way to do so ?

### JwtAuthGuard

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(JwtAuthGuard.name)

  constructor(
    private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private readonly userService: UserService
  ) { }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = request.headers['authorization'];

    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException
    }

    try {
      const firebaseUser = await this.firebaseService.getUserByToken(token)
      request.user = await this.userService.getByEmail(firebaseUser.email)
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(this.canActivate.name, error)
      throw new UnauthorizedException
    }
  }
}
```

### AuthGuardModule

```js
@Module({
    imports: [UserModule],
    providers: [FirebaseService, JwtAuthGuard],
    exports: [JwtAuthGuard]
})

export class AuthGuardModule {}
```

## EDIT

Well, jmcdo29 of the NestJS discord explained me that:

> Your `AuthGuardModule` should export the `UserModule` and the `FirebaseService`. Guards, when used in the `@UseGuards()` decorator, are used in the context of the current controller's module, instead of being looked at as an `Injectable` provider

So I did that way and it did solve my initial issue, but i have another circular dependency issue.

First, let's resume resume the architecture i have:

### AuthModule

- It handles the routes for register, and the routes that send some emails like the password reset or the email verifying.
- It needs the `UserModule` to create a user into my db when i call the register route

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthGuardModule
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, EmailService, FirebaseService],
})

export class AuthModule {}
```

### FileModule

- It handles the file upload and deletion.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => AuthGuardModule),
        BlobModule,
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: File.name, schema: FileSchema }])
    ],
    controllers: [FileController],
    providers: [FileService],
    exports: [FileService],
})

export class FileModule {}
```

### UserModule

- It handles all the users routes.
- It needs the `FileModule`, to check if the avatar exists when it's modified (i have only one route that updates all my users personal data)
- It also needs the `AuthGuardModule` to use my `JwtAuthGuard`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      forwardRef(() => AuthGuardModule),
      forwardRef(() => FileModule),
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService, FirebaseService],
    exports: [UserService, FileModule]
  })

  export class UserModule {}
```

### AuthGuardsModule

- It contains my JWT check guard, and then i check if a user in my db is linked to the connected user
- It needs the `UserModule` to get the user in my db

```
@Module({
    imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule), FirebaseModule],
    providers: [JwtAuthGuard, RegisterAuthGuard],
    exports: [JwtAuthGuard, RegisterAuthGuard, FirebaseModule, UserModule]
})

export class AuthGuardModule {}
```

I could use firebase to store my users avatars and do it front side, but i have to store it in  Azure Blob Storage (it's imposed to my), so the FileModule handle all that thing

So, now, that i solved my AuthGuardsModule -> UserModule circular dependecy thanks to you guys, i have a new circular dependency issue: AuthGuardsModule -> UserModule -> FileModule

I set a forwardRef of the AuthGuardsModule inside the FileModule but nest naturally said me that make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()"

So i put a `forwardRef` to my `FileModule` import inside my `UserModule`, but same thing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, you would need to make use of the `forwardRef` method from the `@nestjs/common` package, which is in charge of handling circular dependency when it occurs. See [Circular dependency - NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

One thing to take into account is the location of your `JwtAuthGuard`. Was it initially inside the `AuthModule` or within another shared module ?

I will assume the guard was initially in your `AuthModule` (for example let's say `/src/auth/guards/auth-guard.ts`).
I also assume that the `FirebaseService` lies within a `FirebaseModule` and is being exported from there, and that the `FirebaseModule` injectables don't need other classes that depends on other circular referencing classes/modules. (*In this case, you would need to indicate Nest how it should handle it by adding more `forwardRef`s within the involved classes/modules*)

Based on the code you provided, you could do something like this:

### AuthModule

```js
@Module({
    imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule), FirebaseModule],
    providers: [...yourProviders],
    exports: [...yourExportedInjectables]
})

export class AuthModule {}
```

### FirebaseModule

```js
@Module({
    imports: [...requiredImports],
    providers: [FirebaseService],
    exports: [FirebaseService]
})

export class FirebaseModule {}
```

### UserModule

```js
@Module({
    imports: [forwardRef(() => AuthModule)],
    providers: [...yourProviders],
    exports: [...yourExportedInjectables]
})

export class UserModule {}
```

NB: You could also use `forwardRef` at the service layer depending on your specific use cases.
NB2: Guards could be grouped within a shared module that could be imported in the `AuthModule`, so that you don't have to specify Nest to forward refs between every modules, but only reference `AuthModule` in the modules using the given guard(s).

Hope it helps !
Again, I don't have much context on your architecture, so I provided code sample based on assumptions.
Don't hesitate to comment / provide more context so I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for your awnser it helped me a lot ! 
I also had the aid of a someone of the nestJS discord, but i'm blocked by another circular dependency that's more tricky to me. I editted my inital post.